# Update function in html5 canvas game isn't working properly

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Jsfiddle :  http://jsfiddle.net/seekpunk/6eeKH/15/

the code :

```
if (this.collection.length > 0) {
                            if (((this.collection[0].blockX + this.collection[0].blockW) >= cw) || (this.collection[0].blockX <= 0)) {
                                this.collection[0].blockSpeed *= -1;
                            }
                            this.collection[0].blockX += this.collection[0].blockSpeed;

                        }
```

the first block from top is drawn twin and i can't figure out why i guess the  problem is in drawing the levels can someone please help me figure out what i did wrong in my code

Comment: What block ? The demo looks fine.

Comment: the first block from top should go left and right due to the update function if you remove this line `if (this.collection.length > 0) {` the console say that `this.collection[0]` is `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am trying to explain this in detail, please bear with me.

Again in your current fiddle, collection array is increasing in its size when `Draw` method is called. You can debug your code, no. of blocks increases to thousands in few seconds.

So now this is how your code works in loop:

1. Your code only modifying position of 1st block i.e. `this.collection[0].blockX`
2. Adds 5 more blocks in collection array with same position. for ex: 
   While `Update` method is called for the second time, below line will get execute

   ```
   addBlocks(4, "Red", 50, 70, 50, 5);
   ```

   So one more block will get added in 6th position of array.
3. While rendering, it draws first block with updated coordinates because of point 1. and draws that block again because of point 2.

This is the reason it is appearing twice.

You need to modify this logic a little bit to solve the problem.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: yesterday i recheck the code and figure out that i should only call the level outside the loop once and it worked perfectly check the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/seekpunk/6eeKH/19/

Answer (score 0):

Now I think you're clearing the platforms from the collection array before any coordinates get chance to be applied and redrawn to the canvas. If you remove the call to 'Blocks.clear()', the platform moves.

Comment: yup i know but shouldn't i clear the array when i want to draw the next level ? to draw some new blocks ? plus if i removed this line the block is duplicated

Comment: Ah, the array doesn't need to be cleared. What does need to be cleared is that canvas. So it's a case of drawing all the blocks first, then, on the next frame you would clear the canvas.

After that, you update the positions of the blocks, etc, then call another draw to the canvas after that.

So what you're actively doing is not having to recreate everything, you're just updating what is already there if that makes sense...

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh i see well thanks for this tip but how do u suggest for me to update my work ? where should i call ctx.clearRect function bcs it's already being called in the update function